# Condition statement for first icon in every row

Tags: php, html, css, conditional-statements

I want to create a condition statement for the first icon in every row to have a "margin-left: 0px" code added to it.  Each icon on my website has a style of margin-top and margin-left of 5 px.  However, the exception needs to be the first of every row.

http://www.juliancelaj.com/portfolio.html

html

```
<a id="small_boardgame" class="small_hoverEffect" style="margin-left: 0px;" href="img/boardgamecover_3.jpg" rel="lightbox[best_portfolio]" title="Uno Board Game Cover" alt="Uno Board Game Cover, image, cards, throwing, machine"></a>
                        <a id="small_video_game" class="small_hoverEffect" href="img/vidgame_3.jpg" rel="lightbox[best_portfolio]" title="Video Game Cover" alt="UEFA Football 2011 Cover, Podolski, Rage360 Concept artbox, speed, emotion"></a>
                        <a id="small_cereal" class="small_hoverEffect" href="img/cerealcover_3.jpg" rel="lightbox[best_portfolio]" title="Cereal Box Cover" alt="Mario, Luigi, Cereal Box Cover, Wario, fire, strawberries, concept, mushrooms, illustration, delicious, design"></a>
```

css

```
#small_boardgame {
    background-image:url(img/boardgamecover.jpg);
}

#small_video_game {
    background-image:url(img/vidgame.jpg);
}

#small_cereal {
    background-image:url(img/cerealcover.jpg);
}

.small_hoverEffect {    
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;  
}

.small_hoverEffect:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);  
}
```

I've added the class small_hoverEffect and a hover effect to it to every div icon on the page.  I was wondering if someone can find a solution using this div class to set a condition where every time one of the icons is first on the new line, it has a "margin-left:0px" condition.  The width of the wrapper is set so the icons drop on the next row after putting 12 icons on the same line each time.

I tried looking at Jonathan's suggestion,

```
.small_hoverEffect:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px !important;    
}
```

but it still did not work.  The first of each row still moved 5px on the left.

Comment: I see a lot of tags in your question but judging from the title you're looking for the [`first-child` CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

Comment: Edited first post.  I tried it Jonathan and it still had no effect.

Comment: No, that's because `.small_hoverEffect` has no children.

Comment: There is no row, your images are floating, they stack to the left. You can not recognize the first element of each row. But you can use a wrapper that make a margin-left: -5px.

Comment: Yes Loenix, I know that.  I was hoping for another way around rather than just moving the wrapper 5px behind.

Comment: The wrapper keeps it floating and "responsive", i don't find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

put your margin on the right hand side instead of the left, this will have the same effect you are wanting.

Comment: Yes it does. It keeps the first icon in every row 0px left margin while retaining a 5px margin in between each.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete margin-left from all icons and do:

```
.icon + .icon /* if element left to element with class "icon" have the same class, do ... */
{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Hope i helped